# Static method on JavaScript class becomes undefined after imported

Tags: javascript

I have this simple JavaScript class with a static method:

```
// test.cjs
class Test {
  static init() {
    console.log('Test.init');
  }
}
exports.default = Test;
exports.Test = Test;
```

Now if I import the `Test` class in another file like below:

```
// index.mjs
const { default: x } = await import('./test.cjs');
console.log(x.init) // <- this will be `undefined`
```

I'm confused here, how come `x.init` becoming `undefined`?

Here's a demo where you can test the code online https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4alfhc?file=test.cjs,index.mjs

Comment: Have you tried debugging this? Do `console.log(x)`!

Comment: Your problem is mixing cjs and mjs modules. Just don't do that.

Comment: Would love to avoid mixing them, but sometimes it just happens. Hence I'd like to figure out what's going on here under the hood. So far I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: Specifically: _either_ use proper commonjs, using `require` and `module.exports`, _or_ use proper ES modules, with `export` and `import`. Especially since you're using a dynamic import instead of a normal import. Why do you need to mix commonjs and ES modules?

Comment: Not really I want to, just ran into such an issue in a library https://github.com/wagmi-dev/references/pull/382, and I would love to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Well, if `x` is like `{default: [class Test], test: [class Test] }`, of course `x.init` is `undefined`.

Comment: You cannot access a property called `default` like that. Trying that will return the value of `exports` instead of `exports.default`. That's by design. "default" has the special meaning of returning the main(/default) export value and therefor overrides the standard behavior. This question does not deserve that downvote.

Comment: @NiklasE. Thanks for your answer, I think I see the problem now. `exports.default` doesn't equal to `module.exports`. When importing `default`, we're actually importing `module.exports` or `exports`. And in my sample code, that `default` equals to `exports`, hence `init` undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a property called `default` (at least not like that). Trying that will return the value of `exports` instead of `exports.default`. That's by design. "default" has the special meaning of returning the main(/default) export value and therefor overrides the standard behavior.

`import(...)` as a function-like dynamic tries to "emulate" the behavior of the `import` statement (static declaration).

See [MDN: import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import?retiredLocale=de) as well as [MDN import()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) and how `{ export1 as alias1 }` is treated differently as `{ default as alias1 }`, it's treated differently even in the highlight on StackOverflow:

```js
import { export1 as alias1 } from "module-name";
import { default as alias } from "module-name";
```

Comment: Right, `{ default }` is not a destructuring here.

Comment: No, `import { export1 as alias1 }` is not treated differently from `import { default as alias1 }`, they are exactly the same. If anything, the special behaviour is on exporting, in particular commonjs modules.